# schedule service only n no. of times between periodic timings[9:00 pm to 12:00 am]

Tags: android, android-service, android-alarms

I've created Service `UploadData` which triggers on <kbd>Start Sync</kbd> event. Added coded in there to schedule Service which runs at 9:00 pm daliy with 1 Hour Interval which runs perfectly fine.

```
 ServiceAlarm.startServiceAlarm();
```

Code snippet:

```
public class ServiceAlarm {
public static AlarmManager alarmMgr;
public static PendingIntent alarmIntent;
static Context context;
public static void startServiceAlarm()
{
    context = MyApplication.getApplication();
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);       
    Intent intent = new Intent(SmartConsultant.getApplication(), UploadData.class);
    alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    // Set the alarm to start at 9:00 a.m.
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 21);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);

    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HOUR, alarmIntent);
    Log.i("Service", "Service Started!");
}

  public static void stopServiceAlarm()
  {
    alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
   }
}
```

But I want these Service to shutdown after 12:00 am [It must run only thrice in a day between 9:00 pm to 12:00 am].

*How One can stop the same service at 12:00 am?*

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a specific method to schedule a stop time. I would say for your specific case the best bet would be to change the setup of your service calls. Have the alarm manager fire at 9. Then when you receive that alarm check the time and if one hour is still before midnight fire another alarm.

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgement.I'm already firing another alarm which cancel the previous one. But still didn't tested it yet. Finger crossed for that.